# C# WPF: Как у клавиши сделать Content в две строки?

Tags: wpf

Как у клавиши сделать Content в две строки? Специальные символы вроде \n \r добавлять не получается.

Comment: Можно в качестве Content положить TextBlock, задать ширину и TextWrapping, тогда он сам увеличится по высоте что бы вместить весь текст.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду `Button`?

Comment: Да, именно Button.

Comment: Текст кнопки фиксированный, или заранее не известно?

Comment: Да нет, текст фиксированный.

Answer (score 5):

В случае фиксированного текста можно использовать `LineBreak`, это разнесёт строки независимо от ширины кнопки:

```
<Button Width="100">
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"> Это <LineBreak/> кнопка </TextBlock>
</Button>
```